# User cannot purchase different item after error: "The item you were attempting to purchase could no be found"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using the [TrivialDrive example](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) to create In-app-purchase for my app. I purposely caused the error

```
The item you were attempting to purchase could no be found
```

but I can't find in the code where the error occurs. The reason I need to know this is that once this error (or a number of other errors) is thrown, user can no longer purchase anything else without restarting the app. This is due to the fact that `flagEndAsync()` is called only during consumption so that if a user tries to buy something else, then the app throws an exception

```
void flagStartAsync(String operation) {
        if (mAsyncInProgress) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't start async operation (" +
                operation + ") because another async operation(" + mAsyncOperation + ") is in progress.");
        }
        mAsyncOperation = operation;
        mAsyncInProgress = true;
        logDebug("Starting async operation: " + operation);
    }
```

I need to be able to safely terminate the asyncTask in case of such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I discovered that this sample, as other samples from Google, is known to be very buggy. I am not sure what the best fix is but right now I use the following check

```
if (mHelper != null) {
  mHelper.flagEndAsync();
}
```

before calling

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

or

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...)
```